# how to convert stdclass into string

Tags: php, laravel

i want to make a two combo boxes in my project , when i'm trying to get the elements inserted in the other one it gives me an error like that : Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string 
how can i solve this problem ? 
this is the controller :

```
 public function getIndex(){
        $category=DB::table('categories')->get(['id','name']);
        $sub=DB::table('subcategory')->where('category_id','=',$category)->get(['id','name','category_id']);
        return view ('contents.in')->with('category',$category)
                                    ->with('sub',$sub);
    }
    public function postIndex(Request $request){
        $name=$request->input('name');
        $sub_id=$request->input('sub_id');
        $category_id=$request->input('category_id');
        DB::table('incategory')->insert(['name'=>$name,'sub_id'=>$sub_id,'category_id'=>$category_id]);
        return redirect('/in');
    }
```

Comment: please, show some code

Comment: $sub=DB::table('subcategory')->where('category_id','=',$category)->get(['id','name','category_id']);

Comment: @MohamedElbiheiry You should probably do join instead in that part ;)

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen ok but sorry in which function of them should th join be done ?

Comment: `$category` is an ,, and you can't just use it inside select statement.. That's the reason for error. You shall do a foreach or do join.

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen can u please write a code of how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why Issue ?** After getting `$category`

```
 $category=DB::table('categories')->get(['id','name']);
```

`$category` is an array

**What You should do ?** You can't just do foreach inside it or do join

**Lazy Way :** (foreach)

```
$sub = '';
foreach($category as $cat)
{
     $sub.=DB::table('subcategory')->where('category_id','=',$cat->id)->get(['id','name','category_id']);
}
return view ('contents.in')->with('category',$category)->with('sub',$sub);
```

Now `$sub` will have your expected result.

I am not sure about your table structure so just i just did a foreach ;) But i want you do use join

**Recommendation :**

1. Use [Eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent)
2. Use [Joins](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#joins)

**Update :**

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/r7MN9/3/) that you require.

`cars` & `phones` are the two array that we pass from the controller

```
cars=new Array("Mercedes","Volvo","BMW","porche");
phones=new Array('Samsung','Nokia','Iphone');

populateSelect();

$(function() {

      $('#cat').change(function(){
        populateSelect();
    });

});


function populateSelect(){
    cat=$('#cat').val();
    $('#item').html('');


    if(cat=='car'){
        cars.forEach(function(t) { 
            $('#item').append('<option>'+t+'</option>');
        });
    }

    if(cat=='phone'){
        phones.forEach(function(t) {
            $('#item').append('<option>'+t+'</option>');
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: $sub.=DB::table('subcategory')->where('category_id','=',$cat->id)->get(['id','name','category_id']);

Comment: Can you able to print `$cat->id` inside foreach ?

Comment: sorry i'm not to good in coding i'm just starting can u help ?

Comment: that's okay .. do `foreach($category as $cat) { echo $cat->id; }`

Comment: instead of the line of $sub or it's another for each?

Comment: Inside the the foreach just have this code `echo $cat->id;`

Comment: Could you able to do `return $category` ?

Comment: Cool, you shall do another thing Just do  `$category=DB::table('categories')->get();` & `$sub=DB::table('subcategory')->get();` and then in your view .. You shall do a foreach

Comment: I will help you in implementation of foreach in view.. First do above two

Comment: they r already done like this 
$category=DB::table('categories')->get(['id','name']);
 and the $sub is as you said like that 
$sub.=DB::table('subcategory')->where('category_id','=',$cat->id)->get(['id','name','category_id']);

Comment: and in my view the for each is like that : 
<select name="category_id" id="category_id"  class="form-control">
                                        <option>  </option>
                                        @foreach($category as $c)    
                                           <option value="{{$c->id}}">{{$c->name}}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                       </select>

Comment: Have you just returned the $category and $sub from your controller ?

Comment: i will post to u the controller and the view wait a second

Comment: I will say you. First have this in your controller `$category=DB::table('categories')->get();
        $sub=DB::table('subcategory')->get();
        return view ('contents.in')->with('category',$category)->with('sub',$sub);`

Comment: i made it like what u said in my controller and the view is working but so i eliminated the function of my combo box and only one is working and the other isn't working !!!!

Comment: What you have in your view ? A dropdown or wat ?

Comment: my view is about inserting an incategory okay , i'm trying to do that : when i check one bow the other one get the elements that is sub of the original one

Comment: You mean. One dropdown will be there, on selecting that another will grow in next item like that ?

Comment: I have updated my answer. It shall be easily dealed in jquery or javascript. You shall follow that

Comment: Also +1 for your interest